# django problem - install the xxx package by putting it on your python path?

Tags: python, django, package

I'm trying to deploy [Everyblock](http://code.google.com/p/ebcode/) specifically its ebblog package on my OSX. I already have both Python and Django installed, unfortunately I am fairly new to both Python and Django.

The readme says something like this:

1. Install the ebblog package by putting it on your Python path.

Here is the complete readme if you need further context: https://github.com/brosner/everyblock_code/blob/master/ebblog/README.TXT

I'm stuck at #1 - when oyu look at the ebblog its a whole django new application directory/file structure, so do I like copy this entier folder to my python's .../lib folder or what?

I can't imagine copying the entire ebblog folder if that is what it meant by the instruction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, installing to the python path means making a python package or module importable, so that when you do

```
import someapp
```

you can then use someapp in your code.
In order to do that you can

1. put the package's path into sys.path (import sys;sys.path.append("path/to/package"))
2. put the path into a file someapp.pth and place someapp.pth inside your dist-packages directory
3. put the path into the PYTHONPATH environment variable

plus some others, see [The Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: yeah that's what i thought too  - if you are writing out a module, you would probably create a a file or package a set of files and drop it in your python's module directory. but in my case, im talking about a whole django directory, do i just drop the whole folder into python's module directory? doensn't make sense to me. you guys may want to check the 2nd link i posted above if it makes send to put the entire folder into python's module directory.

Comment: citing from my link: "When PYTHONPATH is not set, or when the file is not found there, the search continues in an installation-dependent default path; on Unix, this is usually .:/usr/local/lib/python". You can put a whole directory inside dist-packages, iirc. i prefer the .pth way though.

Comment: a django directory is actually just a python package, iirc. it's path (can be any path with sufficient access rights) you make then known to python in one of the above ways.

Comment: hi thanks for trying to help. so okay im going to give it a shot and installing it under /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages this is where django was installed as well so i guess its okay to put the ebblog code here to right?

Comment: hey i think i got it sorted out - yeah i just dropped the whole django app into the site-packages and it gets included to a new django app. thanks so much guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.openplans.org/). It helps to keep dependencies of different projects separate. Here's a good [tutorial](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/).

Comment: hey thanks for trying to help though not sure how virtualenv has anything to do with my problem.

Comment: you create a virtualenv, activate it and then install ebblog therein.

Comment: okay thanks for the extra info though my problem lies on how to "understand" the instruction.